# Why does my filter not return results when I exclude AD groups?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-ldap

I am using `linq to ldap` to generate a list of active Active Directory users. In this case what I have done is exclude useless users(devices and generic users) from the list. However when I do that my search/filter no longer returns results. Here is my code:

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int?page)
{
    int pageSize = 20;
    int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);
    var user = context.Query<ADUser>().ToList().Where
        (u => u.FirstName != null 
        && u.LastName != null
       && !u.DistinguishedName.Contains("ADGROUP1")
       && !u.DistinguishedName.Contains("ADGROUP2"));
     if (searchString != null)
     {
        page = 1;
     }
     else
     {
        searchString = currentFilter;
     }

     ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

     if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
     {
        user = user.Where(y => y.FirstName.Equals(searchString)
            || y.FirstName.Contains(searchString)
            || y.LastName.Equals(searchString)
            || y.LastName.Contains(searchString))
            .OrderBy(e => e.FirstName);
     }

     switch (sortOrder)
     {
        case "FirstName_desc":
            user = user.OrderByDescending(e => e.FirstName);
            break;
        default:
            user = user.OrderBy(e => e.FirstName);
            break;
     }

     return View(user.ToPagedList(pageNumber,pageSize));
 }
```

The part I cannot understand is when I make the following changes to the code above:

change

```
var user = context.Query<ADUser>().ToList().Where
```

to

```
var user = context.Query<ADUser>().Where
//and remove the following code
&& !u.DistinguishedName.Contains("ADGROUP1")
&& !u.DistinguishedName.Contains("ADGROUP2"));
//finally add the following
return View(user.ToList().ToPagedList(pageNumber,pageSize));
```

I can use the search function works as planned. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you try using   Ambiguous Name Resolution (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22653.active-directory-ambiguous-name-resolution.aspx)

context.Query<ADUser>().FilterWith($"(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(anr={searchstring}))")

Comment: Add a Try around code to see if you are getting an exception.

Comment: @WilliamHan is `anr` supposed to be `and`?

Comment: @Skullomania  anr is not and, it is LDAP anr filter.  Look at the link to microsoft for the attributes it use for the search.

Comment: @WilliamHan I tried your suggestion and the paging returned no results without the search filter

Comment: @Skullomania, without any knowledge how  your ad look like.   I would start with just (anr="searchstring")
context.Query<ADUser>().FilterWith($"(anr={searchstring})‌");   And see what is return.    You can further filter it down.